# Intellij navigating between editor tabs/splitters does not work?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am editing with two vertical tabs.  The

```
Window | Editor Tabs | Goto next splitter
```

has no effect - the editing cursor remains in the present Editor Tab.  For curiosity's sake I also tried  "Goto previous splitter" - that also has no effect.

Is there something I am missing here?  Any other shortcut / method to use keystrokes (not Mouse!) to navigate between Editor Tabs?

Note: Ctrl-E is not reliable for this - it sometimes goes to different documents in the same Editor Tab.

**UPDATE**

Apparently the editor "sort of" changes splitters: the titlebar and the Navigation panel change to the file in the other splitter. **But the cursor does not move! The cursor stays in the original place - in the original splitter/editor tab!**  So then what the heck use is it to change splitters - I can not edit or navigate in the new splitter!

Comment: You could try the "switcher" (ctrl-tab) to switch between specific files. But if the cursor isn't following the "Goto next/previous splitter", I'm worried it won't follow the "switcher", either...

Comment: @kuporific  Actually ctl-tab is working better: at least the cursor is working ;) Not a perfect solution - but please make this an answer and I will award.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two other ways to do similar things as "Goto next/previous splitter".

You could try the "switcher" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, OS X & Win) to switch between specific files.

[image: IntelliJ Switcher]

Similarly, you can try the "Recent Files" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, Win; <kbd>⌘E</kbd>, OS X)

[image: IntelliJ Recent Files]

But whatever is causing the cursor to not follow the "Goto next/previous splitter" might make it not follow these options, either...

Comment: For some reason CTL-E is not making cursor follow the splitter. But the  control-tab DOES have cursor working properly. Go figure. Another IJ bug.. but hey IJ still beats eclipse in usability by wide margin.